# How to deny access to /etc/passwd on shared hosting environment

Tags: linux, shared-hosting

I know that `/etc/passwd` file should be world readable and this isn't really a security problem.

My problem is that on a shared hosting environment a malicious user who has access to a hosting account can see the `/etc/passwd` and therefore all the usernames in there.

The malicious user can deface a lot of websites on that server, only because he can see the usernames. He can see what websites are hosted on that server and in case he finds, let's say, deprecated WP or Joomla installation he can mass deface or mass-hack them.

So is there anything, any workaround for this? What can I do So a regular user can't see the contentes of `/etc/passwd`?